# Нужно разбить строку введенную в input

Tags: javascript, html, css

В input ввожу 3 слова через запятую, после клика на кнопку эти слова должна быть отображены в разных div'ах или в разных p.

Answer (score 0):

Весь код писать не буду, так как тут ты не описал проблему, это обычная задача, тут за тебя делать разные задачи никто не будет, вот подсказка:

используешь для начала, чтобы разбить строку в массив

```
var arStr = document.getElementById('id_input').value.split(','); // id_input - ID input, можно другой селектор выбрать
```

затем уже в цикле проходишь по массиву и делаешь что угодно и как угодно