# Как сделать плавное перемещение картинок при mousemove на canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse-event

Есть пример с сайта https://www.madwell.com. Мне нужно сделать такое же поведение картинок при mousemove. Как задать зависимость изменения координат картинки с учетом e.pageX и e.pageY?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/976677/188366

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/977869/330688  вчера был вопрос вот этот в ссылке а я как раз это грызу ..сможешь сделать ответ с пояснением ?

Comment: @MaximLensky актуально?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да